# JSON Enum list deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON Like below

```
{
    "_id": "0FEB6D4B-8DA5-4143-B926-11A7AE4F3B12",
    "device": {
        "name": "test",
        "family": "test"
    },
    "channels": [
        {
            "mcl": 33,
            "vtype": "FLOAT",
            "category": " Current"
        },
        {
            "tag": "OperationMode",
            "vtype": "BYTE",
            "enums": [
                {
                    "0": "Off"
                },
                {
                    "1": "On"
                },
                {
                    "2": "ByPass"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using `Json.net` to deserialize the JSON to C# object. I am not able to manage to convert the enum list. I validated if this is valid JSON. I tried with custom converter & string converter but reader value is `null`. Any quick help appreciated.

Comment: can you show the code that you using for deserializing?

Comment: that's not a valid json

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you want to create an enum at runtime or simply translate it to a List of value and name?

Comment: Nikola its valid json you can check http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Toxantron - I want to create C# object contaning list of enum values & other properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
JObject jR = JObject.Parse(YourJsonString);
JArray oR = (JArray)jR["channels"];     

JArray jA = (JArray)oR[1]["enums"];
foreach (var item in jA)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> enums = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(item.ToString());            
    foreach (var en in enums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(en.Value);
    }
}
```

Fiddler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ziSep1

Comment: Thanks Krunal I know manually parsing will work. I wanted to map this to C# object Device & i want generic way to do this like Json.net support Device device=Deserialize<Device>(json) & it fails when using deseralize

Comment: var device=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Device>(deviceJson,settings); is not working for me I get Unexpected token StartObject when parsing enum.

Comment: Put your Deserialize class. I can get better idea.

Comment: take this sample json
 string personJson = "{\"age\" : \"20\",\"name\": \"amar\",\"Status\":[{\"0\":\"ON\"},{\"1\":\"OFF\"},{\"2\":\"Bypass\"}]}";

 public class Person
    {
        
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public List<Status> Status { get; set; }
    }

public enum Status
    {
        Off,
        On,
        ByPass
    }

My Code for deserialization is

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore;
var person=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(personJson ,settings);

Comment: So there is a well known bug in enum deserialization by Newtonsoft and developers says: "yes, let it stay! <3" ?